# Does command skill give bonus to shooting?

Tags: dark-heresy-1e

If I command a fanatic NPC it looks like I get a +5 bonus per success level to skills. Does this bonus work for shooting/ballistic tests?

Comment: From what I remember, Command was basically translated to "DO IT BETTER", so I believe it does affect that, provided you specify who/what you're affecting

Comment: What is your source for the +5 bonus? I looked through the book and command basically only allows you to give effective orders. And i can't find the fanatic trait for NPC's so could you please list your source for this ability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

In *The Inquisitor's Handbook*, on page 227, it says that a successful Command Test will

> grant a +5 bonus on a single Test **related to that order** for every degree of success attained.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

With this in mind, as long as your Command has something to do with shooting, I would rule that it absolutely applies to Ballistic Skill Tests.